# For loop with list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, stop-words

I have the following code which checks the words in each string in the list analysis_words for whether it is a stopword or not.

```
useful_word = []
for line in analysis_words:
    for word in line:
        if word.split() not in stopwords:
           useful_word.append(word)
```

I am attempting to do the same with list comprehension. My intuitive feeling was something like:

```
for line in analysis_words:
    useful_word = " ".join([word for word in line.split()if word not in 
    stopwords])
```

However, doing that splits the words into characters rather than the string "line" into words. I do not understand why this is the case. How should this be approached?

Comment: `[word for line in analysis_words for word in line if word not in stopwords ]` ?

Comment: Curious, why are you not splitting in the first example, but in the second?

Comment: `set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(analysis_words)) - set(stopwords)`…?

Comment: useful_word = "".join([word for line in analysis_words for word in line if word.split() not in stopwords]) works well, thanks!